# In Svelte and Vite, error "HTMLElement is not defined" shows up after running "npm run dev"

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, svelte, vite

I used a few web components in my Svelte project, but after running `npm run dev` (which is `vite dev` actually), error `HTMLElement is not defined` shows up.

The whole error message is

```
HTMLElement is not defined
ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined
    at /src/components/shared/formkit/classes/composite.js:21:39
    at async instantiateModule (file:///D:/my_project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0fc8e132.js:50548:9)
```

The problematic line of code is

```
// File name is composite.js
export class FormKitComposite extends HTMLElement {
```

But it works fine in Storybook. No error shows up there.

Could anyone teach me how to solve it please?

Thanks in advance!

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "./.svelte-kit/tsconfig.json",

    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        
        "types": [
            "@testing-library/jest-dom",
            "vitest/globals"
        ]
    },

    "include": [
        "decs.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

`vite.config.ts`:

```
const config: UserConfig = {
    plugins: [sveltekit()],

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            $components: path.resolve('src/components'),
            $functions: path.resolve('src/functions'),
            $graphql: path.resolve('src/graphql'),
            $stores: path.resolve('src/stores'),
            $styles: path.resolve('src/styles'),
            $types: path.resolve('src/types')
        }
    },

    server: {
        fs: {
            strict: false
        }
    },

    test: {
        environment: 'jsdom',
        globals: true,
        include: ['src/components/**/*.test.ts', 'src/functions/**/*.test.ts'],
        setupFiles: ['./setup-test.ts'],

        coverage: {
            branches: 100,
            functions: 100,
            lines: 100,
            statements: 100
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because web components cannot be rendered in server side.

To solve it, use dynamic import like

```
    onMount(async () => {
        await import('your file URL');
    });
```